Unable to install Expo React Native (Windows)
After following the docs, npx create-expo-app@latest (using gitbash), I get an error.
Node version : NodeJs 20.18.0
OS : Windows 11
npm warn cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm warn cleanup   [
npm warn cleanup     'C:\\Users\\admin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Projects\\react-native-project\\velo\\node_modules',
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\react-native-project\velo\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes'] {
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\admin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Projects\\react-native-project\\velo\\node_modules\\jsdom\\lib\\jsdom\\living\\nodes'
npm warn cleanup     }
npm warn cleanup   ],
npm warn cleanup   [
npm warn cleanup     'C:\\Users\\admin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Projects\\react-native-project\\velo\\node_modules\\@expo\\json-file',
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\react-native-project\velo\node_modules\@expo\json-file'] {
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\admin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Projects\\react-native-project\\velo\\node_modules\\@expo\\json-file'
npm warn cleanup     }
npm warn cleanup   ],
npm warn cleanup   [
npm warn cleanup     'C:\\Users\\admin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Projects\\react-native-project\\velo\\node_modules\\expo-router\\node_modules',
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\react-native-project\velo\node_modules\expo-router\node_modules\@expo\prebuild-config\build'] {
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\admin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Projects\\react-native-project\\velo\\node_modules\\expo-router\\node_modules\\@expo\\prebuild-config\\build'
npm warn cleanup     }
npm warn cleanup   ],
npm warn cleanup   [
npm warn cleanup     'C:\\Users\\admin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Projects\\react-native-project\\velo\\node_modules\\@react-native\\community-cli-plugin',
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\react-native-project\velo\node_modules\@react-native\community-cli-plugin\node_modules\@react-native\debugger-frontend\dist\third-party\front_end\panels\application\preloading'] {
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\admin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Projects\\react-native-project\\velo\\node_modules\\@react-native\\community-cli-plugin\\node_modules\\@react-native\\debugger-frontend\\dist\\third-party\\front_end\\panels\\application\\preloading'
npm warn cleanup     }
npm warn cleanup   ]
npm warn cleanup ]
npm error code 1
npm error path C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\react-native-project\velo\node_modules\babel-plugin-react-compiler
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c ./scripts/link-react-compiler-runtime.sh
npm error '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm error operable program or batch file.
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-10-08T06_05_40_843Z-debug-0.log
Something went wrong installing JavaScript dependencies. Check your npm logs. Continuing to create the app.
Error: npm install exited with non-zero code: 1

✅ Your project is ready!

To run your project, navigate to the directory and run one of the following npm commands.


I have previously created two other expo apps on this machine almost 6 months ago and had no issue getting it installed. Is there a solution to this?
Thank You in advance.

Please check weather your app is running project folder.
And check your node version and try to delete your node modules and rebuild it with using npm i command

Hey. unfortunately this did not work but I got the fix.
Link to fix

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
